# RoR - Find if part of a string matches an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are a lot of similar questions but I am struggling to find a specific answer.

i have an array of hashes with key of Symbol and a value of Price, I am looking to filter the array to only include the hashes that have a Symbol that ends in the letters ETL

Data looks like:

```
[ [
            {
                "symbol": "ABCDEF",
                "price": "4"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "GHIETL",
                "price": "5"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
array.select { |hash| hash[:symbol].end_with? "ETL" }
```

From the [Ruby docs for select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

> Returns an array containing all elements of enum for which the given block returns a true value.

You can also provide multiple suffixes to `end_with?` if you need to filter by multiple suffixes. For example:

```
array.select { |hash| hash[:symbol].end_with? "ETL", "DEF" }
```

Comment: I am getting undefined method `end_with?

Comment: @timboon You may need to use `hash["symbol"]` instead of `hash[:symbol]`. It looks like my Rails console automatically converted the keys to symbols. Let me know if that works.

Comment: That is not your rails console that did this but the question posted. You see `"symbol": "XYZ"` in `Hash` literal notation means the key is a `Symbol` and as such it will try to convert it to one (`#to_sym` or `intern`). In this case it is cleanly convertible (adheres to symbol notation) so the key simply becomes `:symbol`. If say the key was `"123symbol": "XYZ"` well "123symbol" can not be cleanly conerverted so the `Symbol` would actually be `:"123symbol"`. @timboon The proper notation for `String` keys in a `Hash` would be `"symbol" => "XYZ"`